# Android: New Intent causes NullPointerException in AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-intent, android-asynctask

I have an async task running in background which constantly updates my local sqLite database over the net. Everything works fine, except some random times after i pause my app.  Here is a part of code where I get the error:

```
public class AsyncHardwareDBUpdate extends AsyncTask {
ImageCellAdapter mImageCellAdapter;
GridView dynGrid;
Context mContext;
Boolean mFinished = false;

HardwareSyncReceiver myHardwareReceiver;
private Handler handler;
public AsyncHardwareDBUpdate(Context mContext) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

@Override
protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
    if (mContext != null){
```

The error goes to the following line:

```
        Intent intentHardwareSync = new Intent(mContext,SyncHardwareStateService.class);
```

I cant understand, what can be null here, if I already check if mContext != null. 
The rest of the code:

```
        mContext.startService(intentHardwareSync);
      myHardwareReceiver = new HardwareSyncReceiver();
      //register BroadcastReceiver

      IntentFilter intentHardwareSyncFilter = new IntentFilter(SyncHardwareStateService.ACTION_SyncHardwareStateService);

      intentHardwareSyncFilter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);

      //Handler for the separate Thread


      HandlerThread handlerThread = new HandlerThread("MyNewThread");
      handlerThread.start();

      Looper looper = handlerThread.getLooper();
      // Create a handler for the service
      handler = new Handler(looper);
      // Register the broadcast receiver to run on the separate Thread
      mContext.registerReceiver (myHardwareReceiver, intentHardwareSyncFilter, null, handler);
    }
      return null;
}


05-11 18:07:37.830: E/AndroidRuntime(15063): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
05-11 18:07:37.830: E/AndroidRuntime(15063): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
05-11 18:07:37.830: E/AndroidRuntime(15063):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
05-11 18:07:37.830: E/AndroidRuntime(15063):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
05-11 18:07:37.830: E/AndroidRuntime(15063):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
05-11 18:07:37.830: E/AndroidRuntime(15063):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
05-11 18:07:37.830: E/AndroidRuntime(15063):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
05-11 18:07:37.830: E/AndroidRuntime(15063):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
05-11 18:07:37.830: E/AndroidRuntime(15063):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
05-11 18:07:37.830: E/AndroidRuntime(15063):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
05-11 18:07:37.830: E/AndroidRuntime(15063):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
05-11 18:07:37.830: E/AndroidRuntime(15063): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-11 18:07:37.830: E/AndroidRuntime(15063):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageName(ContextWrapper.java:127)
05-11 18:07:37.830: E/AndroidRuntime(15063):    at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:75)
05-11 18:07:37.830: E/AndroidRuntime(15063):    at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:3350)
05-11 18:07:37.830: E/AndroidRuntime(15063):    at com.smarthomev5.AsyncUpdateThread.AsyncHardwareDBUpdate.doInBackground(AsyncHardwareDBUpdate.java:38)
05-11 18:07:37.830: E/AndroidRuntime(15063):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
05-11 18:07:37.830: E/AndroidRuntime(15063):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
05-11 18:07:37.830: E/AndroidRuntime(15063):    ... 5 more
```

Comment: start the intent in onPostexecute

Comment: This worked, thanks :) Still its kind of an unexpected error..

Answer (score 3):

Sounds to me like a memory leak. Always use `WeakReferences` in `AsyncTasks` when passing a `Context` or `Activity` or other such objects to it. Try something like this:

```
public class ExampleAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

    private final WeakReference<Context> contextReference;

    public ExampleAsyncTask(Context context) {
        this.contextReference = new WeakReference<Context>(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {

        Context context = this.contextReference.get();
        if(context != null) {
            // Do your work
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
        super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);

        Context context = this.contextReference.get();
        if(context != null) {
            // Do your work
        }
    }
}
```

What the `WeakReference` does is to allow for the object it is referencing to be garbage collected. If you hold the reference directly the object cannot be garbage collected and this can cause memory leaks in `Threads` and `AsyncTasks`. This would for example happen when you hold a `Context` reference directly and the `Activity` from which the `Context` object comes is recreated, for example when you rotate your device or the `Activity` is in the background for some time.

In the example above you save the `Context` object in a `WeakReference`, and every time you want to use the `Context` you first have to get it from the `WeakReference`. After you got it from the `WeakReference` you can simply check if it is null or not. If it is not null than it is safe to work with the `Context`. If it is null than the `Context` or the corresponding `Activity` have already been garbage collected and are not usable anymore.

Comment: Thanks for a quick answer, this didnt help to get rid of the error though.. Anyway to make my app more stable I still used your tip :)